# Mockito with Robolectric: "ClassCastException occurred when creating the proxy"

Tags: java, android, mockito, robolectric

I've started hitting a strange ClassCastException in Mockito when using it with Robolectric. When I run the same tests not using Robolectric runner, everything goes fine, no exception is thrown.

Here is stack trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
ClassCastException occurred when creating the proxy.
You might experience classloading issues, disabling the Objenesis cache *might* help (see MockitoConfiguration)
    at com.compassrosetech.ccs.android.test.ObservableCacheDispatcherTest.setUp(ObservableCacheDispatcherTest.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Function0$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$c0163e7f cannot be cast to org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Factory
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:30)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
    ... 29 more
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
@RunWith(ApplicationTestRunner.class)
public class ObservableCacheDispatcherTest {

    @Mock
    private IDataMapper mockDataMapper;

    @Mock
    private ICache mockCache;

    @Mock
    private Function0<Object> mockLoader;

    private ObservableCacheDispatcher cacheDispatcher;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // <-- exception happens when executing this statement
        cacheDispatcher = new ObservableCacheDispatcher(mockCache, mockDataMapper);
    }

    ...
}
```

This is how Robolectric runner looks like:

```
public class ApplicationTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    //Maximun SDK Robolectric will compile (issues with SDK > 18)
    private static final int MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC = 18;

    private static final String ANDROID_MANIFEST_PATH = "../app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
    private static final String ANDROID_MANIFEST_RES_PATH = "../app/src/main/res";

    /**
     * Call this constructor to specify the location of resources and AndroidManifest.xml.
     *
     * @throws org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
     */
    public ApplicationTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(ANDROID_MANIFEST_PATH),
                Fs.fileFromPath(ANDROID_MANIFEST_RES_PATH)) {
            @Override
            public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
                return MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What should I fix to get rid of this exception?

Comment: Interesting! I have just guess that something conflicting with Kotlin/Robolectric. Does Kotlin replace ClassLoader? I hope Kotlin experts will join conversation

Comment: Can you check solution from here https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/75

Comment: @EugenMartynov good point, I've added "kotlin" tag, maybe Kotlin guys would help.

Comment: @EugenMartynov I've tried that solution, but it didn't help. I could be because I'm not using robolectric-gradle-plugin, tests are in a separate pure-Java module.

Comment: Alex, sorry for throwing on you link without good understanding for the problem. After some research I see similar stacktraces when someone is using `PowerMock` (custom class loader)(https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/98). Investigating further

Comment: @EugenMartynov and I've also found another issue which is really close to mine: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/0xOD44czl7k, but still have no clues how to solve or workaround it.

Answer (score 11):

As suggested

> 'disabling the Objenesis cache *might* help'

You can create override MockitoConfiguration.
To do so

- Create a package named org.mockito.configuration under your src/test/java
- Write the MockitoConfiguration class

**Class File**

```
package org.mockito.configuration;

public class MockitoConfiguration extends DefaultMockitoConfiguration {

  @Override
  public boolean enableClassCache() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try to build your code again.

Answer (score 6):

I know question is bit old, but it may help someone looking for the answer.

Adding

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*"})
```

After

```
@RunWith(ApplicationTestRunner.class)
```

Should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem. Basically, you've got some classes that you want Mockito mock and other classes that you want PowerMock to mock. I solved it by adding the `@PowerMockIngore` annotation to my test class and specifying the classes that I wanted to mock using regular 'ol mockito. So in your case, I think adding the annotation:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.package.IDataMapper", "com.package.ICache" ..etc})
```

would work.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not Kotlin issue but Robolectric/Mockito. I believe it is related to classloaders. If you replace Kotlin class with any other library interface (neither JDK nor your project's class) you will see the same exception. Unfortunately I see no solution as I don't understand Robolectric internals. You better to ask Robolectric or Mockito teams about this.

Comment: I'm using `mockito` with `robolectric` without any issue. Similar code works fine for me. Is it specific version of `robolectric` and `mockito`?

Comment: Seems to be. I discovered that the issue is caused different class loaders used by test runner (Launcher/AsmInstrumentingClassLoader) and mockito's classloader (SearchingClassLoader) so stub class is generated via one but Proxy class (that we tried to cast to) was loaded by another one. It requires more investigation and I am pretty sure Mockito or Robolectric teams can do better.

Comment: Wait a minute! Does `Launcher/AsmInstrumentingClassLoader` come from android gradle plugin but not from `Robolectric`? What version of Mockito do you use?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. Both Mockito and Robolectric use classloaders and there are two same class instances in different classloaders that causes test to fail due to ClassCastException. Perhaps there is some workaround however I have no clue

Comment: For me the problems appears when `PowerMock` was added to the picture thats when I start getting this error.

Comment: @JavierSP1209 doesn't `PowerMockIgnore` eliminate the problem?

Comment: I added it for the test where I use PowerMock, but the weird think is that for this particular test class I do use PowerMock at all,and only happens if I run all the tests at once, If I run this particular test class will not fail :/

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround caution!**

Please use at your own risk.

First you have to redefine kotlin function interfaces:

```
interface TestFunction0<R> : Function0<R>
interface TestFunction1<T1, R> : Function1<T1, R>
```

And mock it:

```
val onUpdate: TestFunction0<Unit> = mock()
```

Comment: This does not even compile